# Xcode switch case statement when pressed different Button

Tags: ios, xcode, switch-statement

I have a project with multiple buttons on the first view. I have 10 buttons. The second view is almost the same. There is a difference between the first and the second only in the package of images that are used. I want to use different images when I click the buttons from the first view. So for example:

button 1 on the second view shows a gallery from package1 images
button 2 on the second view shows a gallery from package2 images
...
etc.

Can you please help me?

Regards

Comment: What is the problem? Problem creating the .xib files? Problem connecting IBActions to your IBOutlets? Or do you need a course in iOS development methods?

Comment: let me guess: this has nothing to do with Xcode, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give tag to your buttons.

i.e. YourButton.tag = 100;

give tag to all your buttons and do,

```
 switch (YourButton.tag) {
        case 100:
           // Do your stuff
            break;


       Go through all your buttons//

        default:
            break;
    }
```

Tell me if you need more help regarding this